# Is it possible to change Y-axes shortcut?

Tags: shortcut

Is it possible to change a key <kbd>Y</kbd> to <kbd>C</kbd> for making all keys of X/Y/Z axes nearby?

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible at the moment, as far as I know. Those seem to be hardcoded and not accessible from the Key Map Editor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not so hard as looks like, you can set it in **"User Preferences"** (**"Input"** tab):

- You need to find the drop-down list **"Transform Modal Map"** (it is near end of the list)
- There isn't Y-axis in it, but you can add and setup it by pressing
  **"Add new"** button.
- Next, select **"Orientation Y axis"** and setup shortcut

[image]

> Hey, what about "Shift-Y" which stands for "transform along every axes
>   BUT Y"?

For "Shift-Y" analog use **Orientation Y plane**. This is a final setup:

[image]

Comment: Hey, what about "Shift-Y" which stands for "transform along every axes BUT Y"? It does not automatically work with your solution.

Comment: I never use this. But maybe, it also can be set up, I haven't tried

Comment: @cubrman I've updated the answer

Comment: I need more "like" buttons... Ty man.

Answer (score 1):

For versions 2.80 above, here's what you should do:

Just simply go to *Preferences > Keymap*, and then scroll down until you find *Transform Modal Map*, and within that dropdown you can now change those hotkeys by default.

There's absolutely no need to make your own keymap like the posts above.

I changed mines to <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>
[image: as you can see, I changed mines to XCV instead of XYZ]